# WordPress file missing

Tags: php, wordpress, function

lately, my WordPress sites have been hacked, a lot of popups were showing, due to a PHP code inserted in functions.php of every theme used. I deleted it in every page, but one of them is not working. The website doesn't show up in the browser, and the functions.php file is missing in every theme installed in it. I tried to upload the backup file but still, it disappears. Does anyone have any clue what's happening?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on questions to be asked here. I'm afraid your question is very broad, as there can be many reasons for the described behavior. As with all systems that have been compromised, the best approach is to start a new wordpress installation with fresh files and themes from scratch and carefully transfer the contents step by step

Comment: Do NOT rely on the integrity of your system. Reinstall your complete OS, wipe the harddrive, install everything from scratch! (please, can somebody link the security.stackexchange.com question for a hacked system, I can't find it)

Comment: easy way: contact with your host and restore 4 or 5 days backup, also i inform you that this platform is not provided the suggestion, tools & technologies, you should google and you find a lot of blogs

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed i tried that too, but did't help. Sorry for the broad question and thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Lorry Do You check DB also ? Bad code can be also inserted thru DB too. i suggest use Git for a future) Good Luck.